# Студия не может создать проект - Visual Studio/VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Захожу в Visual Studio 2017 Pro ( активированную ), пытаюсь создать проект, в итоге получаю ошибку: ( скриншот )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Любой проект который Я бы не выбрал ( C#, C++, и.т.д ) везде одна и та же ошибка.
Началось это после обновление самой студии, думал вернуть всё назад ( откатить обновление), но не получилось.
Попробовал удалить всю студию и все следы ещё существования. После перестановки ничего не наладилось  ошибка снова появилась.
Пробовал в корне `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio` удалить файл `privateregistry.bin` но не помогло.
Попробовал переустановить дополнительные компоненты типа:

- `Microsoft Visual Studio C++` все версии до 2017 - без успешно.
- `Net Framework` все части, тоже не помогло.
- `DirectX 9 - 12` - не помогло.

Ключ пробовал снести и заново зарегистрировать, не проканало.

Через **Visual Studio Installer** пробовал изменить ( починить ) недостающие файлы, и тут тоже мимо.

P.S: Проект/Решение открыть могу, и работать с кодом тоже ( компилировать и.т.д ) А вот создать не могу.

Что делать в данной ситуации? Очень срочно нужно исправить.

Comment: Есть мастера кто поможет решить данную проблему? В сети не нашёл ни одной подобной ошибки по данной теме. Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: У меня была похожая ситуация, но проект создавался. Валилось все на стадии то ли запуска, то ли компиляции, с похожей хрен_пойми_про_что ошибкой. К сожалению, подробностей почти не помню, но изучив логи винды, а также взяв в помощь отладчик (кажется использовал x64dbg), случайно заметил, что программа (обычное пустое консольное приложение на C#) помимо системных библиотек почему-то подвязалась на некую dll-ку из недр скайпа. Снес скайп. Не помню, переустанавливал .Net или нет, но все вылечилось.

Comment: А где логи лежат от VS ?

Comment: Вспомнил некоторые подробности. Ругалось на kernelbase.dll, что в system32 лежит. Ошибку эту я нашел в логах винды. Это не логи vs, это стандартные логи системы (раздел system или application). Из них мало что было понятно, но явно указывало на проблему с этой dll-кой. Пробовал просто перерегистрировать dll-ку в системе - не помогло. После чего уже дебаггером нашел связь со скайпом, что было необъяснимо и не понятно, т.к. система была свежеустановленной и из «чужеродного» в ней были только Хром и скайп. Снос скайпа решил проблему. Повторная установка скайпа не привела к появлению ошибки.